# button creation with xml for android app

Tags: android, xml

What is wrong with below code segments ? I have got an error. But I have not solved it yet, because I do not understand.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
    android:text="@string/stop" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonStop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonStart"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
    android:text="@string/start" />
```

error :

No source found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/start').

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this your res/values/strings.xml .

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">EXAMPLE</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>



    <!-- START : MAIN XML STRINGS VALUES -->

    <string name="start">START</string>
    <string name="stop">STOP</string>


</resources>
```

Answer (score 7):

In **res/values/strings.xml** add

```
<string name="start"> start </string>
<string name="stop"> stop </string>
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing Strings.
Add to your res/values/strings.xml the missing Strings.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following code in res/values/string.xml

```
 <string name="start">Start</string>
 <string name="stop">Stop</string>
```

Comment: What, if anything at all, does this answer add that hasn't already been said?